# Loosing 1 Token when supplying for UniSwap v3 Liquidity

Tags: erc-20, uniswap, decentralized-exchange, liquidity-provider

I am trying to add liquidity pool with my Custom erc.20 token, and ETH

If I add 10,000 Tokens - for some reason the UniSwap UI shows 9,999 tokens

Wondering if anyone here has noticed this in their LPs as well?

[image]